# Error while executing Windows Ubuntu Installer executable

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I have burnt a DVD from the Ubuntu 11.10 image file - ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso

I wanted to install Ubunto inside my Windows installation( I am doing this installation on a Windows-7 32 bit as a administrator login). I inserted this DVD in my drive, and started the WuBi(Windows Ubunti Installer) executable, it says installation started, the progress bar shows the progress, but just before it ends, it gives error as mentioned in the snapshot image below. As a result of this error, I have to say Ok and the installation is unsuccessful as I cannot start Ubuntu under windows.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here. How fix it?

Have uploaded the log file as mentioned in the error message [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByuMwWMOjsD0T1VkU2FTbWhTMkNWVU1HLW1CblptZw)

[image]

Comment: try with a virtual iso mounter...it works for me all the time..OR try reading the log file or post it here...

Comment: @Vineet - I read the log file. The error it has are - ERROR  TaskList: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'cd_path' and ERROR  root: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'. Uploaded the log file. Please check OP.

Comment: @Vineet - As u said, installed from the ' mounted' ISO' image using virtual mounter, and it works w/o any errors. Wonder if that means the fiels were not written properly to the DVD or something else. Thanks anyways for the workaround

Comment: pleasure's mine....